# How to get script to insert the whole of user input in C++

Tags: c++, input, printing

I'm new to C++ and I decided to create a small script to get used to the language.

All the script does is that it asks a question to a user, a user then types in a string, and then the script returns with an output with a scripted message followed by the user's input.

My problem is that when a user types in name of more than one word the script will only return the first word, e.g

`What is your name?`

`Donald Duck`

`Welcome Donald`

Below is my script:

```
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    string name;
    cout << "What is your name?\n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Welcome " << name;
    cout << "\nThis is your homepage. Enjoy your stay!" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `std::getline`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  std::cout << "What is your name?\n";
  std::getline(std::cin, name);
  std::cout << "Welcome " << name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If. you hadn't posted this, I wiuld have done it! :p You stole my idea! :))